# Autogenerate User with Kinvey

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kinvey, mbaas

Using Kinvey is there a way to autogenerate users (like in this document: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/guides/users#autogenerated) but for REST or AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autogenerate users is basically a signup with email, which ends up creating a random username and password.

It is possible to do with any of Kinvey SDKs as well as with REST:

1. AngularJS

   ```
   var promise = $kinvey.User.signup({
     email : '<user-email>'
   });
   promise.then(function(user) {
     alert('Kinvey User signup Success.');
   }, function(err) {
     alert('Kinvey User signup Failed.');
   });
   ```
2. REST

> ```
> POST /user/:appKey/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: baas.kinvey.com
> Authorization: [Basic Auth with app credentials]
> Content-Type: application/json
> {"email" : "<user-email>"}
> ```

The user email is optional if you don't enforce Email verification in user settings of your Kinvey app.

In that case, you can do a POST request with an empty body i.e. {}.

References:

1. http://devcenter.kinvey.com/angular/guides/users#signup
2. http://devcenter.kinvey.com/rest/guides/users#signup

Comment: Thanks for the help can you also support this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285825/kinvey-rest-api-upload